# Error: Cannot find module in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, nodes

I am using Jenkins for automation of build deployment. I need to use node fs-extra module but whenever I try to run my Jenkins build, it is showing error

```
Error: Cannot find module fs-extra
```

I have even written a command to install npm package in execute shell section of Jenkin build configuration, but it is still showing error.

Any idea ?

My project has a package.json in which I have defined fs.extra as a dependency. Inside my Jenkins job configuration I am executing npm install under execute shell section and after that inside execute nodeJs script I have written a script

```
var fs = require('moment');

var branch = process.env.branch;
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
var backupSource = ['./dist/index.html', './dist/public/'];
var backupDest = './build_backup_' + branch + '_' + timestamp + '/';

copyFilesToBackup();
function copyFilesToBackup() {
    if (backupSource.length == 0) {
       process.exit();
    }
    else {
        var src = backupSource.shift();
        if (src.indexOf('public') > -1) {
            backupDest = backupDest + 'public';
        }
        fs.copyRecursive(src, backupDest, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
                return;
            }
            console.log("Copied successfully : ", src, backupDest);
            copyFilesToBackup();
        });
    }
}
```

but Jenkins build throws error on very first line

```
Error: Cannot find module 'fs.extra'
```

I have even print the current directory and it is same in which node modules have been installed, but still I am getting this error in Jenkins only.

Comment: can you please add more details about what your job does? what step do you use to trigger npm? what OS? generally I would check if the node executable is in the PATH, and if it uses the correct node modules directory.

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  Did you ever find a fix?